# How can I make the origin of a smoke emitter follow a Bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to make an icosphere with a quick smoke effect follow a Bezier curve, but I am unable to get the origin to follow the curve. So the smoke just follows the origin along the axis of deformation. How would I ether get the smoke to move with the icosphere, or get the origin to follow the Bezier curve?

Comment: Could you please show us a couple pictures of whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to blender world, Ahsaan.  Your question is rather brief and has no diagrams or blend file provided, so you may get some inapplicable answers.

The quick-effects // smoke   should have created an Inflow behavior on your animated object.  Verify you don't have this set to a static Geometry behavior (once at startup)

[image]

And this object should be following the Bezier curve:

[image]

Which should produce the desired effect:

[image]

As was produce by [image]

Comment: First of all I am extremely sorry for not including any further information, I'm very much new to blender and really all of this. But secondly thank you very much, this has been a roadblock for him for a while now and your assistance was greatly appreciated.